# How to give user a config file for a composer package?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, config

How can I publish a config file for a user which user can edit global variables for my composer package, and how to read it from package? What is the best practice for this?

It's like Laravel artisan's `vendor:publish` command for config files.
Note: this is not a Laravel package.

Comment: You need copy a config file from your package to your project.

Comment: If you are developing a package and want to support Laravel framework, write a [ServiceProvider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/packages#configuration).